# JavaScript center Align Texxt

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make some UI buttons in Javascript.
So I made the following function that is supposed to draw one when its called.

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
let cell = 32;
function Button (buttonText,buttonFunction,buttonPositionX,buttonPositionY,collor,buttonSizeX,buttonSizeY){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(buttonPositionX*cell,buttonPositionY*cell,buttonSizeX,buttonSizeY);
    ctx.fillStyle = collor;
    ctx.fillRect(buttonPositionX*cell+5,buttonPositionY*cell+5,buttonSizeX,buttonSizeY);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "30px Changa one";
    ///////////////////////////////////
    let textX = 30*buttonText.length;
    textX = ( buttonSizeX - textX ) /2; 
    ctx.fillText(buttonText,textX,buttonPositionY-30);
    ///////////////////////////////////
}
Button('Play',1,17,2,'green',cell*4,cell*2);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <canvas id = 'canvas' width = '1280' height = '640'></canvas>
    </head>
</html>
```

I need to center the text of the button inside the button , however its either not working because I cant use `.length` propriety on buttonText because it becomes a constant when its declared only inside the function ( there are no errors in the console though ) , either it gets some crazy value for some reason and it draws the text on the outside of the canvas.

So here is my question.

> How can I center the given text inside the button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline styles to the button.

```
ctx.style = "text-align: center";
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
```

Edited: see below fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/f2tkexrL/130/